# xdg-open opens a specified htm file but ignores the tag (#) location within the page

Tags: shell-script, browser, xdg-open

I have a function in a bash script (openWebPage) which I want to open a web page and navigate to an id tag within the page.

The url components are held in variables

```
PIXPAGE="/home/bu5hman/pix/pixpages/media.bu5hman.2005-.video.htm"
TT="tt0078435"
```

The call to the function composes the variables

```
openWebPage "$PIXPAGE#$TT"
```

Within the function, if I hard code the call to my default browser (seamonkey) directly with a file url which has a tag specified

```
/home/bu5hman/Installs/seamonkey/seamonkey "file://$1"
```

the page opens at the required tag, however using

```
xdg-open "file://$1"
```

opens the web page at the top but does not navigate to the tag within the page.

When the browser is called directly it opens with the full url and tag in the navigation bar, but when called using xgd-open it opens with the url stripped of the tag (#tt0078435) in the navigation bar.

It appears that xdg-open strips the tag from the url before passing it to the application.

Aside from using a script to interrogate the system for the default browser and composing a direct call, is there a way to either prevent xdg-open from stripping the tag or an alternative cross platform call to open the web page at the tag?

Comment: Did you forget to quote somewhere? A hash in bash starts a comment.

Comment: i have tried escaping (\#) to no joy. if I promote to single quotes then the expansion of the variables doesn't happen and the call fails. The point is that the passed url works perfectly when i call it directly from the script with the double quotes but if I use xdg-open the #tt12345678 component is lost. If xdg-open parses a url then my question question remains ..... can I stop it parsing the argument?

Comment: Can't duplicate. `xdg-open "http://example.com/#123"` works exactly as expected.

Comment: Is the tag in the url in your navigation bar?

Comment: It does show there.

Comment: Just changed my default browser to firefox and tried again and it works exactly as expected. So it appears to be an xdg-open / seamonkey issue, even though both are mozilla based.

Comment: I wonder if it could be an issue related to its .desktop file or startup script...

Comment: In what way? Anything you suggest for me to try?

Comment: Track down the seamonkey .desktop file and see if it invokes a script that uses incorrect quoting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68825/discussion-between-bu5hman-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found thanks to pointers from @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

The issue was actually in the way `xdg-open` passes an argument to the default application.

If the default application is registered in [kde desktop](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/kmenuedit.pdf) so as to expect a url (%u)

```
/home/bu5hman/Installs/seamonkey/seamonkey %u
```

then the whole argument passed to `xdg-open` is used as a url and the browser navigates to the tag.

if the %u is omitted then the argument passed to `xdg-open` is tested to see if it is a file and then stripped of information from the # in the url (from the `xdg-open` script)

```
# If argument is a file URL, convert it to a (percent-decoded) path.
# If not, leave it as it is.
file_url_to_path()
{
    local file="$1"
    if echo "$file" | grep -q '^file:///'; then
        file=${file#file://}
        file=${file%%#*}                                #<----------
        file=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/\?.*$//')
        local printf=printf
        if [ -x /usr/bin/printf ]; then
            printf=/usr/bin/printf
        fi
        file=$($printf "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's@%\([a-f0-9A-F]\{2\}\)@\\x\1@g')")
    fi
    echo "$file"
}
```

and the page is only opened at the top.

In my case firefox had been registered with %u and seamonkey without, which is why I had different behaviour in the two browsers.